# Python replace url lib.requests with requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I have the following function written with urllib, but I'd like to update it to be reliant only on requests for fetching the info, and BeautifulSoup for parsing the xml data. Is that possible?

```
import re
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import xml.dom.minidom

def magnetic_variation(coordinates):
    rc = []
    lat, lon = coordinates
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'lat1': lat, 'lon1': lon, 'resultFormat': 'xml', 'startMonth': now.month})
    url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateDeclination?%s" % params) 
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(url.read())
    for node in dom.getElementsByTagName("declination")[0].childNodes:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc.append(node.data)
    rawdata = ''.join(rc)    
    variation = str(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", rawdata)[0])
    return round(float(variation),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, bs4

def magnetic_variation(coordinates):
    rc = []
    lat, lon = coordinates
    params = {'lat1': lat, 'lon1': lon, 'resultFormat': 'xml', 'startMonth': now.month}
    url = requests.get("http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateDeclination", params=params) 
    dom = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text)

# parse the dom

return round(float(variation),2)
```